# Lack of performance in PostgreSql redis_fdw

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, redis

Is it normal that inserting a single two-column line in a [redis_fdw](https://github.com/pg-redis-fdw/redis_fdw) scalar/hash table lasts **longer** than in a regular Postgres table (in average 0.6 ms vs 0.06 ms)? I use Redis to speed-up my postgres, but why to use it if it dose the opposite thing?

PostgreSql 9.3, Redis 2.8.4

Comment: You move data between *two different* databases. This incurs a cost. Inserting a two-column line in Postgres is already fast. Which timings do you get if you insert directly to Redis?

Comment: @joanolo It is near to sql's speed.

Comment: You can count on the inter-Database costs to outweight any possible advantage